# login to Huawei Wingle e8231s - 2 with vb.net return login error

Tags: vb.net, authentication, sms, httpwebrequest, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to send sms from win7 pc/64bit, visual studio 2015, vb.net,
using Huawei Wingle e8231s - 2 GSM Wifi Stick,

The GSM Wifi Stick web interface makes calls to API that I'm trying to mimic.

To do so, a Login request must done first, with header contains both verification token and cookie(session id), which I can get by requesting from the wingle webserver.

I always have The response code is 108006 which is incorrect username or password.

My code:

```
 Public Sub Main()

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo")
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    ' Read the content.  
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Extract the header: cookie is the session id. 
    Dim SesStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<SesInfo>") + 9
    Dim SesEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</SesInfo>")
    Dim TokStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<TokInfo>") + 9
    Dim TokEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</TokInfo>")
    Dim vSessionId As String = responseFromServer.Substring(SesStart, SesEnd - SesStart)
    Dim vToken As String = responseFromServer.Substring(TokStart, TokEnd - TokStart)

    ' Clean up the streams and the response.  
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
    'Call SetSesAndToken(response)
    'Make the api call using the session ID extracted
    request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/user/login")
    request.Headers.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", vToken)
    request.Headers.Add("Cookie", vSessionId)

    Dim PassWordEncoded As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin"))
    Dim Myxml As String = "<?xml version:'1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <request>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password>" & PassWordEncoded & "</Password>
            <password_type>4</password_type>
            </request>"

    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Myxml)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    request.ContentType = "text/xml"

    Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    End Using


    Dim ReceiveStream As Stream
    Dim encode As Encoding
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    Using myresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If myresponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim message As String = [String].Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", myresponse.StatusCode)
            Throw New ApplicationException(message)
        End If
        ReceiveStream = myresponse.GetResponseStream()
        encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
        sr = New StreamReader(ReceiveStream)
        responseFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd()
        MsgBox(responseFromServer)
    End Using
```

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution but unfortunately, it didn't work, it return error 120005, which means that a parameter is missing, this is because the token is not in the cookie, and when I add the token in addition to the cookie container, it give the error 10008 as usual

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a cookie container and keep your container with the cookies for subsequent calls. You first do a GET to retreive the security token and/or other cookies then you make other calls like login etc.

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim FormData As String = "login_user=&wallet=0x29a450d32a95b0b08230b93cc9ac328db81dc80e"
    Dim cookiejar As New CookieContainer
    Dim webreq As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://somesite.org")
    Dim responseReader As StreamReader
    Dim responseData As String
    Dim requestWriter As StreamWriter
    webreq.Method = HttpMethod.Get.Method

    webreq.CookieContainer = cookiejar
    Dim xxx As HttpWebResponse = webreq.GetResponse()
    responseReader = New StreamReader(webreq.GetResponse.GetResponseStream())
    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
    responseReader.Close()

    webreq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://somesite.org")
    webreq.Accept = "text/html"
    webreq.Method = HttpMethod.Post.Method
    webreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    webreq.ContentLength = FormData.Length
    webreq.CookieContainer = cookiejar

    requestWriter = New StreamWriter(webreq.GetRequestStream)
    requestWriter.Write(FormData)
    requestWriter.Close()

    responseReader = New StreamReader(webreq.GetResponse.GetResponseStream())
    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
    responseReader.Close()
```

Code to Authenticate your modem:

```
Public Sub Main()
' Hitting the starting page
Dim cookiejar As New CookieContainer
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/user/state-login")
request.CookieContainer = cookiejar
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
' Read the content.  
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
' Extract the header: cookie is the session id. 
' Dim SesStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<SesInfo>") + 9
' Dim SesEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</SesInfo>")
' Dim TokStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<TokInfo>") + 9
' Dim TokEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</TokInfo>")
' Dim vSessionId As String = responseFromServer.Substring(SesStart, SesEnd - SesStart)
' Dim vToken As String = responseFromServer.Substring(TokStart, TokEnd - TokStart)

' Clean up the streams and the response.  
reader.Close()
response.Close()
' Hitting the login api endpoint
'Call SetSesAndToken(response)
'Make the api call using the session ID extracted
request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/user/login")
request.CookieContainer = cookiejar

Dim PassWordEncoded As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin"))
Dim Myxml As String = "<?xml version:'1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <request>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>" & PassWordEncoded & "</Password>
        <password_type>4</password_type>
        </request>"

Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Myxml)

request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
request.ContentType = "text/xml"

Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using


Dim ReceiveStream As Stream
Dim encode As Encoding
Dim sr As StreamReader
Using myresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    If myresponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim message As String = [String].Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", myresponse.StatusCode)
        Throw New ApplicationException(message)
    End If
    ReceiveStream = myresponse.GetResponseStream()
    encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    sr = New StreamReader(ReceiveStream)
    responseFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd()
    MsgBox(responseFromServer)
End Using



void SaveUrl(string sourceURL, string savepath) {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string sResponseHTML = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savepath, false)) {
            sw.Write(sResponseHTML);
        }

        string[] ImageUrl = GetImgLinks(sResponseHTML);
        foreach (string imagelink in ImageUrl) {
            HttpWebRequest imgRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imagelink);
            imgRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpWebResponse imgresponse = (HttpWebResponse)imgRequest.GetResponse();
            //Code to save image
        }
    }
```

Test it out I am not a .net guy. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the modem using token and the cookie(session-id), I extract them and pass the cookie and the token as headers of the request.
the API signature for login:
drive.google.com/open?id=1GMlZsa48j5Ps3kcf2D0JHejygc8SIPOV
a HiLink documentation (another version but share most of the features)
http://www.bez-kabli.pl/viewtopic.php?t=42168#

Comment: they are in the cookie container. you just have to pass the container with each call so the cookie stays with it

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner approach is to create a Session for HTTP requests instead of hitting individual api endpoints. In this case the cookies will be sent by default.If you have enough time you can explore AT commands also. Good luck!

Code to Authenticate your modem:

```
Public Sub Main()
' Hitting the starting page
Dim cookiejar As New CookieContainer
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/user/state-login")
request.CookieContainer = cookiejar
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
' Read the content.  
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
' Extract the header: cookie is the session id. 
' Dim SesStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<SesInfo>") + 9
' Dim SesEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</SesInfo>")
' Dim TokStart As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<TokInfo>") + 9
' Dim TokEnd As Short = responseFromServer.IndexOf("</TokInfo>")
' Dim vSessionId As String = responseFromServer.Substring(SesStart, SesEnd - SesStart)
' Dim vToken As String = responseFromServer.Substring(TokStart, TokEnd - TokStart)

' Clean up the streams and the response.  
reader.Close()
response.Close()
' Hitting the login api endpoint
'Call SetSesAndToken(response)
'Make the api call using the session ID extracted
request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.8.1/api/user/login")
request.CookieContainer = cookiejar

Dim PassWordEncoded As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin"))
Dim Myxml As String = "<?xml version:'1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <request>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>" & PassWordEncoded & "</Password>
        <password_type>4</password_type>
        </request>"

Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Myxml)

request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length
request.ContentType = "text/xml"

Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using


Dim ReceiveStream As Stream
Dim encode As Encoding
Dim sr As StreamReader
Using myresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    If myresponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim message As String = [String].Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", myresponse.StatusCode)
        Throw New ApplicationException(message)
    End If
    ReceiveStream = myresponse.GetResponseStream()
    encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    sr = New StreamReader(ReceiveStream)
    responseFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd()
    MsgBox(responseFromServer)
End Using



void SaveUrl(string sourceURL, string savepath) {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string sResponseHTML = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(savepath, false)) {
            sw.Write(sResponseHTML);
        }

        string[] ImageUrl = GetImgLinks(sResponseHTML);
        foreach (string imagelink in ImageUrl) {
            HttpWebRequest imgRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imagelink);
            imgRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpWebResponse imgresponse = (HttpWebResponse)imgRequest.GetResponse();
            //Code to save image
        }
    }
```

Please test it out I am not a .net guy. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that, the modem depends totally on JavaScript and Ajax calls, can't find a com port to make AT calls.

Comment: Would appreciate an example

Comment: Ok can you send the api endpoint signatures of login page of modem,login endpoint and sendsms endpoint?

Comment: this is a website with comprehensive info about the hilink web interface of the modem

Comment: any chance that you have time will make my day:)